# sbt installation does not set up scala; cant run scala files

Tags: scala, sbt

I followed instructions on [this site](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) because I didn't want to [work with](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) intellij.

With this installation, scala is not available as a command. How would I go about running .scala files?

Comment: The easiest way is to create directory, `cd` there, create your `.scala` file with `main` method and then `sbt run` (`sbt ~run` will rerun when you update file). If you need REPL: `sbt console`.

Comment: **SBT** _(~Simple~ Build Tool)_ is a project management tool for Scala/Java projects - similar to **Maven**. It won install Scala as program in your environment. But, instead, will allow you to manage the Scala version to use in each of your projects _(and other things like dependency management and Jar packaging)_ - this allows you to separate your global environment from your project environment _(somewhat similar to a Python virtual environment)_.

Answer (score 3):

Installing sbt doesn't get `scala` REPL for you. If you have `sbt` in your PATH variable, then you can use `sbt console` command to do and verify simple scala commands.

Otherwise you need to install scala separately.

The easy way to install scala and sbt is to use sdkman. Follow steps [here](https://sdkman.io/install).

```
  curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
  source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
  sdk install sbt
 sdk install scala
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. Does that mean that every time sbt is invoked, a new 'installation' of scala is created in that directory? I was imagining that there was some global scala install that was being referenced by sbt

Comment: no. It won't install scala every time you invoke sbt command. It download version of scala library jars  specified in `build.sbt` for the first time and then reuses the same library next time onwards. If you change the version in `build.sbt` again it downloads the new scala library version.

Comment: Where does sbt install scala ?